# YouTube Analytics API Error: Forbidden

Tags: r, youtube-api

I've authenticated and build my query and receive the 403 response as Forbidden.

I authenticated with using **httr** example

```
# 1. Find OAuth settings for google:
google <- oauth_endpoint(NULL, "auth", "token", base_url = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2")

# 2. Register an application at https://code.google.com/apis/console#access
myapp <- oauth_app("google", "{my app id}.apps.googleusercontent.com", secret = "{my secret}")

# 3. Get OAuth credentials
cred <- oauth2.0_token(google, myapp, scope = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/yt-analytics.readonly")
```

After authorizing in the browser the R console prints 'Authentication complete."

The query is

```
query <- "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/analytics/v1/reports?
ids=channel%3D%3D{my channel id}
&start-date=2013-01-01
&end-date=2013-07-31
&metrics=views
&dimensions=day"
```

The token for authorization is passed in header as

```
token <- paste("Authorization: Bearer ",cred[[1]], sep="")
```

I've tried the request with both **httr** and **RCurl**

```
# RCurl    
api.response <- getURL(query, httpheader = token)

# httr - I think this is the right way to add the token to the header
url_signer <- sign_oauth2.0(cred[[1]], as_header = TRUE)
api.response <- GET(query, config = url_signer)
```

The api.response is unfortunately not very descriptive

```
{ 
  "error": 
  {  
  "errors": 
    [
    {    
      "domain": "global",    
      "reason": "forbidden",    
      "message": "Forbidden"   
    }
    ],  
   "code": 403,  
   "message": "Forbidden" 
  }
}
```

I'm not sure where else to look and have read through the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/channel_reports#Reports).

Comment: If you're getting a 404, then you haven't authorised correctly. If you want anyone to help, you'll need to provide a reproducible example with pointers to the appropriate youtube api documentation. It's also a little strange to use both RCurl and httr.

Comment: I didn't see how to get the header in the GET function from httr so used RCurl but the authentication was easy with httr. Is this the right way to include the header in httr - GET(query, add_headers(Authorization = token))? It returns the same 403 Forbidden error. Thanks for any direction or help.

Comment: You can use `c(verbose(), url_signer)` to get verbose output from curl - that will help ensure you're sending the right details.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? I'm experiencing the same thing

Answer (score 0):

From experience, a 403 Forbidden response from the analytics API can mean a few things about the video you're trying to pull analytic information for:

- The video is private and not uploaded by you
- You have not claimed ownership on the video
- The video does not exist, or has been deleted by the uploader
- The uploader account has been terminated
- You have a claim on the video that falls under one of the following statuses:

  - Inactive
  - Potential

When in doubt, contact your partner manager/TAM. I hope this helps!